# Memory leak in Java and process termination

Tags: java, memory-leaks

If I create objects using Java, then when the program runs to completion, for sure the garbage collector has done its jobs. But say if I make an object, then suspend the process (using Ctrl+Z) and then send the kill signal to that process, will garbage collection be done, or will it leak memory?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java, specifically. Any binary - a JVM or otherwise - will release its memory when it is killed. Otherwise, you could just spawn, suspend and kill processes to cause a computer to run out of memory.

Comment: But no, GC would not be done. The memory would just be released back to the OS.

Comment: Does the OS keep track of memory allocations made by a certain process? If not, then how does it get released after manual termination of process?

Comment: No, it keeps track of the memory allocated to the whole process. The process is given a block of memory to do with as it pleases. This doesn't need to be garbage-collected afterwards: you just overwrite its contents.